# How to make a deployment from D365 Development environment to UAT

Tags: x++, dynamics-365-operations

Need to take my development environment code to UAT environment

Tried the procedure mentioned here, but not able to understand all steps:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/dev-tools/access-instances

So can anyone answer in the stepwise who has prior experience with this service deployment in D365?

Comment: The link provided is about deploying of development environments. The question seems to be about deployment of application changes, which is described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/deployment/create-apply-deployable-package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried these steps to deploy the changes on UAT from DEV environment:

1. Configure your TFS on Visual Studio
2. Do code check-in and commit/push your changes
3. Go to [https://dev.azure.com/{{company_name}}/{{company_name}}/_build](https://dev.azure.com/%7B%7Bcompany_name%7D%7D/%7B%7Bcompany_name%7D%7D/_build)
4. Open Pipeline
5. Under the summary section, there will be mentioned commit numbers, so click on that and copy that commit message and paste it somewhere (not mandatory, but helps to better track the deployment)
6. Click on the most recent build showing up
7. Click on Published button under Related section
8. Expand Package, then download the DeployableRuntime zip by clicking on that.
9. Rename the downloaded file as {{filename}}+{{commit_message}}+.zip
10. Go the https://lcs.dynamics.com
11. Head to asset library from top menu bar
12. A list will pop-up, select Software Deployable Package
13. For some browsers, you might need to scroll up, by default that menu action is missing, click on + sign to Add a deployment
14. Upload that zip file you just renamed downloaded from azure portal
15. Move to home page of LCS project
16. Select the environment in which you want to have the deployment, for our case it's UAT
17. Click on maintain, select the package, then Apply.

Deployment Done..